# Json output required at client side

Tags: curl, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2 4.7.0 and wso2dss 3.0.0..I have created a service in which my client sending clientcode in request and i have to responce with clientname and clientid.I have created a proxy serivce and sequence for it like :

```
<inSequence onError="fault">
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="clientcode"
                   expression="//clientcode/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <payloadFactory>
            <format>
               <p:Select_Clientid_Op xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                  <xs:clientcode xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$1</xs:clientcode>
               </p:Select_Clientid_Op>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//clientcode/text()"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send receive="Client_Seq2.0">
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/muser_DataService2.0/"
                        format="soap11">
                  <suspendOnFailure>
                     <errorCodes>101500,101501,101506,101507,101508,101503,50000</errorCodes>
                     <initialDuration>30</initialDuration>
                     <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                     <maximumDuration>300</maximumDuration>
                  </suspendOnFailure>
               </address>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence onError="fault">
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
```

Sequence:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Client_Seq3.0">
   <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
   <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" name="clientid" expression="//s:clientid/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" name="clientname" expression="//s:clientname/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" name="clientshortname" expression="//s:clientshortname/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   <log>
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="clientid" expression="get-property('clientid')"/>
   </log>
   <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="get-property('clientid')=''">
      <then>
         <payloadFactory>
            <format>
               <ResponseJSON xmlns="">
                  <Exception> Data Not Found</Exception>
                  <Status>404</Status>
               </ResponseJSON>
            </format>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send/>
      </then>
      <else>
         <payloadFactory>
            <format>
               <ResponseJSON xmlns="">
                  <Body>
                     <Datalist>
                        <clientid>$1</clientid>
                        <clientname>$2</clientname>
                        <clientshortname>$2</clientshortname>
                     </Datalist>
                  </Body>
                  <Status>200</Status>
               </ResponseJSON>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" expression="//s:clientid/text()" evaluator="xml"/>
               <arg xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" expression="//s:clientname/text()" evaluator="xml"/>
               <arg xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" expression="//s:clientshortname/text()" evaluator="xml"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
      </else>
   </filter>
</sequence>
```

curl :

```
 curl -v -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -d '{"clientcode":"youtility"}' http://youtility-desktop:8282/services/PartyClientid3.0
```

I got xml format output at client side as :`<ResponseJSON><Body><Datalist><clientid>21405735715865601</clientid><clientname>Youtility tech</clientname><clientshortname>Youtility</clientshortname></Datalist></Body><Status>200</Status></ResponseJSON>`

and i required JSON format as:

```
{
  "ResponseJSON": {
    "Body": {
      "Datalist": {
        "clientid": "21405735715865601",
        "clientname": "Youtility tech",
        "clientshortname": "Youtility"
      }
    },
    "Status": "200"
  }
}
```

where should i change my code?or i have to change my payloadfactory?if yes then how?

Answer (score 1):

You should set "messageType" property before Send mediator.

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
<send/>
```

Comment: thanks mephist.. i have tried it ..but when i add this property before send mediator is doesn't give any response at client side..

Comment: Did you enable MessageFormatter/Builder fro application/json in axis2.conf?

$ESB_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml:

`<messageFormatter contentType="application/json"                          class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>

<messageBuilder contentType="application/json"                         class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>`

Answer (score 0):

since your expecting JSON format you need to update playLoadFactory correctly.

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
 <format>{ "clientid": "$1", "clientname": "$2", "clientshortname": "$3"}</format>
 <args>
 <arg expression="$.clientid" evaluator="json"></arg>
 <arg expression="$.clientname" evaluator="json"></arg>
 <arg expression="$.clientshortname" evaluator="json"></arg>
 </args>
 </payloadFactory>
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
```

try this

http://technotes.dilan.me/?p=246

Comment: thanks Dakshika..I'm getting output but it doesn't in Json format..It is like this: '<ResponseJSON><Body><Datalist><clientid>21405735715865601</clientid><clientname>Youtility tech</clientname><clientshortname>Youtility tech</clientshortname></Datalist></Body><Status>200</Status></ResponseJSON>' Why this??

Comment: It doesn't give property format..as we have predecided format of output.

Comment: I have tries it too..and it's giving same response

Comment: In your out sequence you need to add <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/> _after_ the payload factory and before the <send/>  mediator. Unfortunately we have to do this manually even when using a payload factory with media-type="json" (due to backward compatibility reasons).

Comment: try to add <log level="full"/> before <send/> in out sequence and trace

Answer (score 0):

Remove -H "Content-Type:application/json" from your curl command and try once